# Avoid PostgreSQL type evaluation in CASE statements

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, types, jsonb

I want to select a column key value if this column is a jsonb.
If it's not a jsonb, I want to simply select the column.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (pg_typeof(mycolumn)::text LIKE 'jsonb') 
        THEN mycolumn->>'mykey' 
        ELSE mycolumn 
    END
FROM mytable;
```

It does not work, because somehow the `mycolumn->>'mykey'` is still evaluated for columns that are not of type JSONB.

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: [...] ->> unknown
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Is there a way to make PostgreSQL type check accept this statement, or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can do this by casting the query result to `text`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (pg_typeof(mycolumn)::text LIKE 'jsonb') 
        THEN (mycolumn::text::jsonb)->>'mykey' 
        ELSE mycolumn::text 
    END
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. By the way I have columns that cannot (timestampstz for example).